# Visiting the port of Antwerp

Tags: ships, antwerp

The city of Antwerp has an enormous port and all sorts of related infrastructure. People have told me that it is stunning, so I would like to visit it.

I asked in the tourist information centre, but they pretty much told me that visiting the port is not possible at all and it is not even visible from the nearby Museum aan de Stroom.

What are my options if I want to see at least part of the port without renting a car and driving around the place?

Comment: Do you mean the container port??

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Yes.

Comment: You won't be able to "drive around the place". It's a restricted area, and you need a (legit) reason to go in.

Comment: I know in the nearby (and larger) Rotterdam port, there are boat tours around the harbour. I am not sure if such a thing exists in Antwerp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ports are highly controlled environments and do not allow visitors. They have multiple layers of security and other restricted zones.

In short - unless you work for a logistics company, you can't get inside the port.

This is true not just in Antwerp, but pretty much anywhere there is a port that handles international cargo.

It would be like asking to visit the area of the airport where they process all the luggage and get it ready for loading on airplanes.

The best you can hope is a tour of the waterways; for example on the [Flandria](https://www.visitantwerpen.be/en/tours/boat-tours-en/flandria-en):

> You can choose an **extensive port cruise** or the ‘Best of Antwerp’
>   cruise, in which you improve your knowledge of the port and the city
>   as you slip past on the Scheldt.
>
> In the mood for something more? Then go for one of the theme cruises.
>   Savour the atmosphere on an Aperitif Cruise, for example, or enjoy
>   Antwerp at sunset during the Candlelight Cruise. Or why not go on a
>   scrumptious tour of discovery with the Beer, Chocolate & Diamonds
>   cruise?
>
> You can get a breath of fresh air on the outside deck or hunker down
>   in the cosy atmosphere of the indoor lounge, as you enjoy the
>   tranquillity of the water and the beautiful view of the Antwerp
>   skyline and the banks of the Scheldt. Welcome aboard!

Comment: I tried to get more information about the port cruise, but it seems that this attraction is only available during the warmer half of the year. As if the ships and containers were any different during winter, right? I'll try again this summer if I get there. Thanks for the answer.